# How to increment a id when appending elements using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#More').click(function(){
  $("div2").append("<div class=fieldBlock><label >Parameter Name: </label><select  type=text id=name2  name=name2 ><option></option></select> </br>");
});
```

I have created a button that appends a parameter drop down select when the button is clicked. I want to give each appended select a different id. For example, when  button is pressed for first time, that select will have id name2, then if button is pressed again, the new append select will have id name3, and so forth. Any way of doing this?

Comment: Create a counter variable and interpolate it into the HTML.

Comment: I tried creating a counter, but the i would not increment. An example would be nice

Comment: you didn't close the div tag, and your class does not have quote wrapper.. :\

Comment: `...id='name" + counter + "'....`

Comment: You could select them with the `:nth-child` jQuery selector instead of using their ID (depending on the situation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shoud work for you.

[Fiddle of it working.](https://jsfiddle.net/z6xk38uq/)

```
var count = 0;
$('#More').click(function(){
   $(".div2").append("<div class='fieldBlock'><label >Parameter Name: </label><select id='name" + count + "'  name='name" + count + "' ><option></option></select></div> </br>");
   count++;
});
```

Comment: I am not sure why this was downvoted, but it does indeed do exactly what OP has requested. (not to mention me fixing the incorrect HTML structure)

Comment: I dont know why someone downgraded it either. But thank you, this worked. I will select it as answer as soon as possible

Comment: Do you know how in jquery you can call something by its id and count? For example,   $('name').append, i want to append name + count. How do i call that?

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = 1;

$('#More').click(function(){
    var str = "select" + id; //select1, select2, select3, etc....
    $("div2").append("<div class='fieldBlock'><label>Parameter Name: </label>
    <select  type='text' id='" + str + "' name='" + str + "' ><option>
    </option></select></br></div>");
    id++;
});
```